# Global Methods In MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a method that will need to be called by various controllers and various actions. Where is the correct place to put this method and how would i call it from other controllers. Cant seem to find anything by searching, so if someone could point me in the right direction i would appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: This usually depends on the function and responsibilities, none of which are posted. Is it a static method?

Comment: Sounds like you could use a base, Controller-derived class for all your controllers.

Comment: Maybe if this functionality is the same for all controllers you could use global filter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like a job for a base controller:

```
public class BaseController : Controller 
{    
   // Do your common stuff here...
}
```

Then inherit `BaseController`:

```
public class MyController : BaseController
{    
   // Your code goes here...
}
```

Comment: Why base controller? Not all controllers need access to this method. It no doubt gets the job done but I will like to learn the reasoning behind this approach.

Comment: @Yogesh _"Not all controllers need access to this method"_ - then don't let those controllers inherit from it.

Comment: @CodeCaster my point is shouldnt it be static methods instead of base controller

Comment: The question is not concrete enough to give such advise, also, I try to use `static` as little as possible.